# Symbol for "is closest to"?

Tags: probability, notation

I am writing a paper on probabilities and we have to find a $k$ such that $P_n(k)$ is "closest to" $P_0$.

$P_0$ is getting 4-of-a-kind in a five card hand in a standard 52 card deck.

$P_n(k)$ is probability of getting $k$-of-a-kind in an $n$ card hand in some modified 88 card deck.

I want to say that getting 5-of-a-kind (there are 11 suits) in a 5 card hand for our modified deck produces a probability "most similar" or "closest to" $P_0$.

So would this be ok for a theorem?\

$P_5(k)$ is the probability closest to $P_0$ when $k=5$. That is, $\lvert P_0 - P_5(k)\rvert$ is minimized for $k=5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either say exactly what you said above, or, more formally: $|P_i-P_n(k)|$ is minimized for $i=0$.

Comment: Could you check my edit above?

Comment: Yep, exactly. I see no better way of making that rigorous. Accept, please? :P

Comment: I can in two minutes, it won't let me < 15min or something

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. :)